# How to create an update method for MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb

I am trying to create an update method in Jupyter Notebooks using Python and MongoDB, but whenever I run the program with my current update method, I get a TypeError saying "'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'animals' method on a 'Database' object it is failing because no such method exist." How do I fix the update method to where it changes the "outcome_type":"Transfer" to "outcome_type":"Adopt" for a dog with "name":"Rhonda"? Here is my code:

animal_shelter.py

```
    from pymongo import MongoClient
    from bson.objectid import ObjectId

    class AnimalShelter(object):
    """ CRUD operations for Animal collection in MongoDB """

    def __init__(self,username,password):
        # Initializing the MongoClient. This helps to 
        # access the MongoDB databases and collections. 
        # init to connect to mongodb without authentication
        self.client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:55996')
        # init connect to mongodb with authentication
        # self.client = MongoClient('mongodb://%s:%s@localhost:55996/?authMechanism=DEFAULT&authSource=AAC'%(username, password))
        self.database = self.client['AAC']

    # Complete this create method to implement the C in CRUD.
    def create(self, data):
        if data is not None:
            self.database.animals.insert(data)  # data should be dictionary  
            return True # Tells whether the create function ran successfully
        else:
            raise Exception("Nothing to save ...")

    # Create method to implement the R in CRUD.     
    def read(self, data):
        return self.database.animals.find_one(data) #returns only one

    # Update method to implement the U in CRUD.
    def update(self, data, {"$set": {"outcome_type":"Adopt"}}):
        if data in self.database.animals():
            print("Data exist, ", end =" ")
            self.database.animals.update(data)
        else:
            print("Does not exist")`
```

testing_script.ipynb

```
    from animal_shelter import AnimalShelter
    # now need to create the object from the class
    shelter = AnimalShelter("aacuser","Superman")
    data = {"age_upon_outcome":"2 years","animal_type":"Dog","breed":"Dachshund","color":"Black and tan","name":"Rhonda","outcome_subtype":"SCRP","outcome_type":"Transfer","sex_upon_outcome":"Female"}

    # if shelter.create(data):
    #    print("Animal added")
    # else:
    #     print("Failed to add animal")
    
    # Calls the read function
    # shelter.read(data)

    # Calls the update function
    if shelter.update(data):
        print(data)
```

I tried changing

```
    self.database.animals.update(data)
```

to

```
self.database.animals.update({"$set": {"outcome_type":"Adopt"}})
```

and I was expecting to get a different outcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This form of the update method works:

```
def update(self, data, new_values):
    if self.database.animals.count(data):
        print("Data exist")
        self.database.animals.update(data, new_values)
    else:
        print("Does not exist")
```

And this call works:

```
if shelter.update(data, new_values):
print(data)
```